# Como listar registros usando un filtro LIKE

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy desarrollando mi primer proyecto con PDO PHO, quiero listar unos registros de la base pero filtrando con Like

En la clase tengo la función Buscar por Nombre de la siguiente manera

```
 public static function buscarPorNombre($nombre){
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . self::TABLA . "  where    dec10 like ?");      
    $consulta->execute(array("%".$nombre."%"));
    $registros = $consulta->fetchAll();              
    return $registros;      
}
```

Tabla es una constante, pero al ejecutar no me devuelve nada, ni tampoco me da errores.
Espero sus comentarios.

Comment: Pregunta tonta pero necesaria... Una consulta similar contra la base de datos directamente, devuelve resultados?

Comment: Realice la consulta sql directa sobre el mysql directamente y si devuelve valores, al realizar por el PDO no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que tienes es correcto. El hecho de que no devuelva datos puede deberse a que:

- no estás conectado correctamente a la base de datos
- realmente no hay registros coincidentes con el criterio pasado en `$nombre`.
- hay un error en el nombre de la tabla obtenido a través de `self::TABLA`
- hay un error en el nombre de la columna `dec10`
- que la columna donde buscas no está declarada como *case insensitive* (ci) <sup><kbd>1</kbd></sup>

Si quieres mejorar el código puedes establecer los controles antes mencionados en el flujo del código.

```
 public static function buscarPorNombre($nombre){
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    if($conexion){
        $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . self::TABLA . " WHERE dec10 LIKE ?");
        $like="%".$nombre."%";
        if ($consulta->execute(array($like))){
            $registros = $consulta->fetchAll();
            $resultado = ($registros) ?  $registros : array("error"=>"No se encontraron datos con el criterio $like");          
        }else{
            $resultado=array("error"=>"Ocurrió el siguiente error en la consulta".$stmt->errorInfo()[2]);
        } 
    }else{
        $resultado=array("error"=>"No se pudo conectar a la base de datos. Revise el código de conexión");
    }
    return $resultado;      
}
```

Lo que hace el código anterior es ir controlando todo el flujo del código, almacenando las eventualidades en una variable llamada `$resultado`. Cuando ocurre algo inesperado, el código asignará a esta variable (que será siempre un array) una clave `error` con el mensaje de lo ocurrido. De este modo, desde la llamada a la función podrás verificar si la clave `error` existe en el resultado y optar o no por mostrar al usuario el mensaje de error.

En caso de no haber error, pasarías entonces a tratar los datos obtenidos en la consulta.

Por ejemplo:

```
$findByName=TuClase::buscarPorNombre("pedro");
if (array_key_exists('error', $findByName)) {
    echo $findByName["error"];

}else{

    //Trabajar con los datos porque devolvió resultados

}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad a ti y a cualquiera que revise esta pregunta.

#### Notas:

---

<sup><kbd>1</kbd></sup> No nos detendremos demasiado en este asunto, porque se alejaría demasiado del propósito general de la pregunta. No obstante, una consulta con `LIKE` podría fallar por ese motivo. Si quieres explorar esta posibilidad, puedes ver [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967)  a la pregunta: [Se puede verificar en DB si es igual a un string?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132799/29967) .

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que no trabajo con PHP, pero LIKE requiere comillas simples.

```
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . self::TABLA . "  where    dec10 like '?'");
```