# Se puede verificar en DB si es igual a un string?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando  verificar en un campo de una tabla de mysqli si es = a un string exacto.

Es decir:

```
 $consulta = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM productos WHERE productos.stock = 'si' ";
```

Esta bien formulado?

Comment: `SELECT count(*) as total FROM productos WHERE BINARY productos.stock = 'si'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende de cómo sea tu columna:

### - Si la columna `stock` es *case insensitive* (ci)

La consulta:

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM productos WHERE productos.stock = 'si'
```

Contará en las columnas cuyos valores sean:

- sí
- SI
- sï
- sI
- si
- ... y cualquier otro extraño si

---

### - Si la columna `stock` NO es *case insensitive* (ci)

Sólo contará cuando el valor sea:

- si

No te contará ni siquiera si el valor es: `SI` o `Si` o `sI`.

---

### Prueba de concepto

Vamos a hacer algunas pruebas con código.

<kbd>**[VER FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rHc2AEUyHD8kz5eyjXMmDm/0)**</kbd>

#### 1. *`COLLATE` con case insensitive (ci) en el `CREATE TABLE`*:

```
   /*Ejemplo de case insensitive en el CREATE*/
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabla_ci_20180122 
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        texto VARCHAR(25)
        
    )COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci, ENGINE=INNODB;


    INSERT INTO tabla_ci_20180122 (texto)
        VALUES 
        ('si'),('SI'),('sí'),('sï'),('no')
    ;

   SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM tabla_ci_20180122 WHERE texto='si';
```

**Salida:**

```
total
4
```

---

#### *2. `COLLATE` case sensitive (cs) en el `CREATE TABLE`*

Se usan los mismos datos anteriores.

```
   /*Ejemplo de cs en el CREATE*/
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabla_no_ci_20180122 
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        texto VARCHAR(25)
        
    )COLLATE latin1_general_cs, ENGINE=INNODB;


    INSERT INTO tabla_no_ci_20180122 (texto)
        VALUES 
        ('si'),('SI'),('sí'),('sï'),('no')    
    ;

   SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM tabla_no_ci_20180122 WHERE texto='si';
```

**Salida:**

```
total
1
```

---

#### 3. ***`COLLATE` de la tabla por defecto, y una columna con `cs` explícitamente***

El `COLLATE` se puede establecer para toda la tabla, pero algunas columnas pueden tener su `COLLATE` propio, diferente del de la tabla.

```
   /*Ejemplo de una tabla con COLLATE mixto: se establece una columna cs explícitamente*/ 
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabla_mixta_20180122 
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        texto_ci VARCHAR(25),
        texto_no_ci VARCHAR(25) COLLATE latin1_general_cs
        
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;    
    
    INSERT INTO tabla_mixta_20180122 (texto_ci, texto_no_ci)
        VALUES 
        ('si','si'),('SI','SI'),('sí','sí'),('sï','sï'),('no','no')
    ;
```

#### Prueba (columna *case insensitive*):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) mixta_ci FROM tabla_mixta_20180122 WHERE texto_ci='si';
```

**Resultado:**

```
mixta_ci
4
```

#### Prueba (columna *case sensitive*):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) mixta_no_ci FROM tabla_mixta_20180122 WHERE texto_no_ci='si';
```

**Resultado:**

```
mixta_no_ci
1
```

Comment: Es de "case insensitive", y he probado tal cual formule arriba y a funcionado. Gracias por la información.

Comment: @jukxz, pero si está en mayúscula o acentuada no funcionará. Si quieres que los considere todos iguales, acentos incluídos, le puedes dar una `COLLATION` que sea *case insensitive* (son las que terminan con `ci`, por ejemplo: `utf8_general_ci`, `utf8_spanish_ci`).

Comment: Edite mi comentario me habia faltado el "insensitive" es de CI. Lo cual no sabia que funcionaba para eso. Agradezco tu respuesta.

Comment: me hubiera gustado esperar a ver los detalles de parte del usuario.