# MySQL uso de LIKE

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando conseguir los datos de la tabla `empleados` que tengan `ape1em` empezando por `a` hasta `l`, solo que no me muestra ninguno.

```
select nomem, (numhiem+2) as invitaciones, numhiem as obsequios
from empleados
where ape1em LIKE '[A-L]%'
ORDER BY nomem asc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia la parte del like donde esta el % coloque *:

LIKE **'[A-L]*'** ORDER BY nomem asc;

Lo que hace es devolver los registros cuyo contenido inicien con una letra de la A a la L seguidas de cualquier cadena. No se si es lo que estas buscando.

O también puedes utilizar la expresión regular REGEXP

where ape1em REGEXP '^[A-L]';

Comment: Usando LIKE [A-L]*' no me da ningún resultado

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que usar algo como `LIKE [A-L]*'` funciona en otros manejadores de bases de datos, pero no en MySQL.

La consulta se resuelve efectivamente usando expresiones regulares. Pero hay al menos dos problemas:

- La [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) indica que se use `REGEXP` para **búsquedas complejas**: *A regular expression is a powerful way of specifying a pattern for a complex search.*
- `REGEXP` no usa los índices de la tabla, por lo que el rendimiento se puede ver afectado.

Aportaré otra manera de hacerlo, usando `BETWEEN`. Esta función sí usará los índices de la tabla.

Por definición, `BETWEEN` es usado para encontrar datos **entre** dos rangos conocidos, que es lo que quieres aquí.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    nomem, 
    (numhiem+2) as invitaciones, 
    numhiem as obsequios
FROM 
    empleados
WHERE
    LEFT(ape1em, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'L'
ORDER BY nomem asc;
```

Si la tabla o la columna `ape1em` no tienen un `COLLATE` que sea *case insensitive* (ci), puedes indicarle a la consulta que resuelva ese posible problema indicando que se ejecute con un `COLLATE` que sea *case insensitive*:

```
SELECT 
    nomem, 
    (numhiem+2) as invitaciones, 
    numhiem as obsequios
FROM 
    empleados
WHERE
    LEFT(ape1em, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'L'
ORDER BY nomem asc 
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

De ese modo, te traerá los registros que empiecen con letras como `A, á, â, b, B... l, L`. **Eso será necesario solamente en el caso que la tabla o columna no tengan un `COLLATE` que termine en *`_ci`***. (Para más detalles sobre el problema de `COLLATE` y *case-insensitive (ci)* \ *case-sensitive (cs)*, puedes consultar [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967)).