# Busqueda de un texto en mysql con acentos

Tags: php, mysql

que tal

tengo una tabla "cursos" y un buscador web en php

la tabla está en utf8_general_ci, la web en utf8
En la tabla estan guardados con acento, o sea si busco "técnico" me aparecen resultados, pero si busco "tecnico" no aparece nada...

la consulta basicamente es

```
Select * from cursos where titulo like '%".texto."%'
```

Desde ya agradezco sugerencias

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el recorrido [CLICK AQUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: por otro lado una solución rápida seria cambiar todas las vocales por comodines con php, de modo que se vea `Select * from cursos where titulo like '%t_cn_c_%'` para "técnico" por ejemplo

Comment: Héctor, en algunos casos ciertas columnas tienen un `COLLATE` específico, el cual impera sobre el `COLLATE` de la tabla. Tal puede ser el caso de la columna `titulo`. [Mira esta respuesta con una prueba de concepto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967). Puedes salir de dudas ejecutando esta consulta: **`SHOW CREATE TABLE cursos;`**, ahí te aparecerá la información del estado actual de tu tabla y de sus columnas. Si todo está bien a ese nivel, entonces puede que sea un problema del objeto conexión a la base de datos, el cual debe tener también un charset `utf-8`.