# Codificacion adecuada para México

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, codificación

Tengo una duda, estoy por crear una base de datos en MySQL, posteriormente utilizaré los datos desde HTML y PHP, pero tengo duda acerca de la codificación que debo usar al crear la base de datos para que el español de México se muestre correctamente la `ñ`, acentos y caracteres especiales. He visto varias opciones entre las más comunes son las siguientes pero no se cual utilizar:

> utf8_general_ci,
>
> utf8_unicode_ci,
>
> utf8mb4_general_ci,
>
> utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Ojalá me puedan ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Leete [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894582/what-mysql-collation-character-set-should-i-use-for-english-and-spanish) pregunta, va a solucionar tu duda!

Comment: Hola @Salvador si el OP no sabe inglés, no crees deberías traducir la respuesta, colocarla aquí y dar referencia a la original? te recomiendo leas esta entrada en meta al respecto de lo que te digo https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3643/qu%C3%A9-debemos-hacer-con-las-recomendaciones-que-mandan-a-leer-una-respuesta-en-in

Comment: Para bases de datos en español puedes usar: `utf8_spanish_ci`... pero ojo, debes manejar la codificación adecuadamente en los diferentes niveles, o tendrás caracteres raros. Por cierto, el `ci` significa *case insensitive*, lo cual quiere decir que el sistema considerará como iguales estos valores: `valor, Valor, VALOr, valoR`.... etc. [Ver aquí para más detalles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967)