# JSON no devuelve nada

Tags: json

tengo el siguiente codigo, que cuando le ingreso un valor, no devuelve nada. No se donde esta el error, he intentado de todo.

```
$json=array();



 if(isset($_GET["cat"])){

            $cat=$_GET["cat"];

            $conexion = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);
            $consulta='select nombre,descripcion,facebook,horario,direccion,ruta_i,ruta_i6,ruta_i2,ruta_i3,ruta_i4,ruta_i5 from negocio inner join categoria on negocio.cat = categoria.id where cat =' .  $cat;
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

                while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $json['negocio'][]=$registro;


            }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            echo json_encode($json);

 }
```

Si le ingreso el valor 1 me deberia de devolver los datos que corresponden, pero no me devuelve nada. si le ingreso un valor que no corresponde por ejemplo 2, me devuelve un arrays vacio [].

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> array(1) { ["negocio"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(11) { ["nombre"]=>
>   string(15) "Alma de Lagunas" ["descripcion"]=> string(124) "En nuestro
>   desayuno buffet vas a probar delicias caseras, mermeladas artesanales,
>   variedad de infusiones y jugos naturales. " ["facebook"]=> string(44)
>   "https://www.facebook.com/almadelagunashotel/" ["horario"]=>
>   string(15) "Siempre abierto" ["direccion"]=> string(16) "Av. Irigoyen
>   152" ["ruta_i"]=> string(55)
>   "http://emiibarra6.com/DBremota/images/almadelagunas.jpg"
>   ["ruta_i6"]=> NULL ["ruta_i2"]=> string(56)
>   "http://emiibarra6.com/DBremota/images/almadelagunas2.jpg"
>   ["ruta_i3"]=> string(56)
>   "http://emiibarra6.com/DBremota/images/almadelagunas3.jpg"
>   ["ruta_i4"]=> string(56)
>   "http://emiibarra6.com/DBremota/images/almadelagunas4.jpg"
>   ["ruta_i5"]=> string(56)
>   "http://emiibarra6.com/DBremota/images/almadelagunas5.jpg" } [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmG7z.png)=>
>   array(11) { ["nombre"]=> string(13) "Hotel Guamin�" ["descripcion"]=>
>   string(13) "Hotel Guamin�" ["facebook"]=> string(38)
>   "https://www.facebook.com/hotelguamini/" ["horario"]=> string(15)
>   "Siempre abierto" ["direccion"]=> string(17) "San Martin y Alem"
>   ["ruta_i"]=> string(54)
>   "http://emiibarra6.com/DBremota/images/hotelguamini.jpg" ["ruta_i6"]=>
>   NULL ["ruta_i2"]=> string(55)
>   "http://emiibarra6.com/DBremota/images/hotelguamini2.jpg"
>   ["ruta_i3"]=> string(55)
>   "http://emiibarra6.com/DBremota/images/hotelguamini3.jpg"
>   ["ruta_i4"]=> NULL ["ruta_i5"]=> NULL } } }

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es el campo `cat`?  Prueba a imprimir la consulta: `echo $consulta;` la copias y la pegas en el manejador de BD y la ejecutas a ver si no tiene errores de sintaxis. Si `cat` no es numérico la consulta es errónea, el valor debe ir entre comillas simples.

Comment: @A.Cedano esta es la consulta: select nombre,descripcion,horario,facebook,direccion,ruta_i,ruta_i2,ruta_i3,ruta_i4,ruta_i5,ruta_i6 from negocio inner join categoria on negocio.cat = categoria.id where cat =1

Comment: Pruébala directamente en la base de datos y dinos si trae datos. Puede haber un error de sintaxis o no tener registros relacionados. Por ejemplo, ¿esta columna `ruta_i` no se llamará `ruta_i1` ?

Comment: @A.Cedano ahi edite la publicacion con una captura.

Comment: Prueba la variable haciendo esto cuando cierres el bloque `while`: **`var_dump($json);`** Otra cosa que puede estar ocurriendo es que la conexión no se esté haciendo. Mejor te sugeriré un código controlado, además, estás mezclando estilos, lo cual es una mala práctica. Ahora te propongo algo mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba este código controlado, te dirá la situación del json con el `var_dump` al final.

```
$json=array();
$cat=( !empty($_GET["cat"]) ) ? $_GET["cat"] : NULL;

if ($cat) {
    $conexion = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);
    if ($conexion) {
        $consulta='select nombre,descripcion,facebook,horario,direccion,ruta_i,ruta_i6,ruta_i2,ruta_i3,ruta_i4,ruta_i5 from negocio inner join categoria on negocio.cat = categoria.id where cat =' .  $cat;
        $resultado=$conexion->query($consulta);
        if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($registro = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $json['negocio'][]=$registro;
            }
        } else {
            $json['error']='Cero filas halladas';
        }
    } else {
        $json['error']='No hay conexión';
    }
} else {
    $json['error']='No se posteó valor para cat';
}

var_dump($json); #Esto es sólo para prueba, luego lo quitas.
echo json_encode($json);
```

#### Correcciones

- Un código que controla el flujo del programa, asignado una clave `error` al dato final que te servirá para determinar si hubo errores y cuáles fueron.
- Uniformidad, usando en todo momento el estilo orientado a objetos, ya que antes mezclabas con el estilo procedural, más antiguo y más *verboso*  y más feo :)

#### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tu forma de consultar aquí no es segura, el código podría estar expuesto a ataques de inyección SQL. No he hecho esa corrección para no confundirte demasiado, pero es bueno que lo tomes en cuenta, te documentes sobre ese riesgo y uses para estos casos consultas preparadas.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, me fueron de mucha ayuda. Sobre la seguridad me voy a informar y aplicar todo lo necesario. Gracias!

Pero sigue sin funcionar, que hace el var_dump? Por que si lo dejo, devuelve datos pero no me funciona en la App que estoy desarrollando, si lo saco, no devuelve ningun datos, como en el principio.

Comment: No se si servira de ayuda, pero funcionaba cuando solamente tenia un solo registro (fila). Le agregue mas datos y a partir de ahi dejo de funcionar.

Comment: Edito la publicación con el resultado del var_dump

Comment: @IbarraEmiliano ahí tienes los datos, sólo tienes que darles el uso requerido en tu programa.

Comment: Es que desde el programa me aparece otro error con el var_dump. No se porque antes me funcionaba y ahora no. El error dice: FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0x22 (at offset 1078). Sabras de que puede ser este error.?

Comment: Si lees la respuesta, puse un comentario en el código donde decía que el `var_dump` era sólo para prueba. Ya puedes quitarlo para que el código devuelva solamente el JSON, que es lo que el cliente espera para manejarlo en el código. Es probable que, para dar coherencia al código, tengas que verificar si el `response` contiene una clave `error`, para poder informar al cliente cuando haya errores.

Comment: ahi saque el var_dump. No devuelve nada ahora. Sinceramente no se :(

Comment: @IbarraEmiliano ¿estás poniendo **solamente esto al final**: `echo json_encode($json);`?  ¿Podrías mostrar la forma en que estás manejando la respuesta, **en el cliente**?

Comment: Si, estoy poniendo solo eso, lei algo de un problema con el Encoding. json_encode solamente retorna utf-8. Pero tengo todo bien. No se por que me retorna vacio.

Comment: No te retorna vacío. El `var_dump` muestra que hay datos. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump( json_encode($json) );`?

Comment: muestra: bool(false)

Comment: string(31) "{"error":"Cero filas halladas"}"   cuando no hay filas

Comment: @IbarraEmiliano No puede mostrar dos resultados, o muestra `bool(false)` o muestra `string(31) "{"error":"Cero filas halladas"}"` ¿? Al parecer no está encontrando filas. Y revisa si no tienes más de un `var_dump` que es lo que parece indicar el `false`

Comment: Lo solucione!!! hice un update a todas las tablas sacando las tildes, y ahora me devuelve los datos!!! Tengo un problema con el Encoding. tendre que subir datos sin tildes. Gracias igualmente, me ayudaste un monton :)

Comment: @IbarraEmiliano realmente no tienes por qué subir datos sin tilde. Quizá lo mejor sería que declares las columnas del tipo `ci`, que significa *case insensitive*. Eso hará que te considere iguales valores como: `José, Jose, JOSÉ, jOsé`
 ... etc. [Ver más detalles sobre el tema en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967)