# ¿Cómo encontrar subcadena, insensible a tildes?

Tags: php, acentos, tildes

Estoy trabajando en un formulario con un campo para buscar usuarios con autocompletar. Estoy guardando la información en un archivo, quedando algo como:

```
$users = [
    1 => ['login' => 'mpaz', 'name' => 'María de la Paz'],
    4 => ['login' => 'hglez', 'name' => 'Héctor González'],
    5 => ['login' => 'ctorres', 'name' => 'Carlos Torres'],
    7 => ['login' => 'mgomez', 'name' => 'Margarita Gómez'],
    9 => ['login' => 'cramirez', 'name' => 'Claudia Ramírez'],
    10 => ['login' => 'hectorm', 'name' => 'H. Miguel Ruiz'],
];

function busca($valor, $users) {
    foreach($users as $id => $v) {
        if(mb_stripos($v['login'], $valor) !== false || mb_stripos($v['name'], $valor) !== false) {
            echo '<p>' . $v['login'] . ' - ' . $v['name'] . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

La búsqueda se activa cuando el usuario teclea al menos 3 caracteres en el campo y ejecuto la función anterior para encontrar las coincidencias.

Si el usuario teclea **ari**

> **Resultado esperado:**
> mpaz - María de la Paz
> mgomez - Margarita Gómez

> **Resultado obtenido:** (No reconoce caracteres con tilde)
> mgomez - Margarita Gómez

¿Cómo realizar la comparación para que sea insensible a caracteres con tilde o diacríticos?

P.D. `foreach` resulta entre un 15% y un 60% más rápido que `array_filter`, dependiendo de la cantidad de elementos en el arreglo y los datos buscados.

Comment: Al leer esto en tu pregunta: *«Tratando de optimizar, estoy guardando la información en un archivo»* comprendo que escogiste un camino de optimización erróneo. Renuncias a una caractarística de la base de datos que habría consistido en declarar esas columnas de un tipo `ci` (que significa Case Insensitive) resolviendo así el problema. Para una columna declarada `ci`, todos estos valores son iguales: `José, Jose, JosE, JosÉ, JOSe, JoSÉ`. Querer hacerlo fuera de ese contexto no es optimizar, es complicar las cosas y hacer el proceso más costoso.

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo para MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967). Si usas otro manejador, supongo que también tendrá forma de indicar el `COLLATE` de la tabla/columna.

Comment: Claro el tener que sacar los datos de su hábitat natural (BD) para guardarlos en otro sitio (archivo) es mucho más lento y mucho más costosos. No es sólo el grosor que tendría el archivo, sino que los archivos no indexan los datos como hace la BD, por lo que encontrar algo es mucho más lento, aparte de que en tu arrray, como ya dije antes, estás intentando reflejar algo que la BD te sirve de forma natural (por medio de índices y demás) sin tener que volver a guardar los datos en otra parte.

Comment: Si estás usando una base de datos, como MySQL, internamente ya viene optimizada para hacer esas búsquedas omitiendo tildes y eñes, siempre y cuando el collate esté correcto. Si no tienes un motor de base de datos, o te resulta complicado montar uno, puedes usar SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar `preg_match()` y normalizar el input basado en una lista de equivalencias. Y usar `\W?` para incluir los casos en los que la letra venga precedida de algún símbolo.

```
$equivalencias = [
  "a" => "aAáÁ",
  "e" => "eEéÉ",
  "g" => "gG"
];
$data = [
  "Héctor González",
  "Carlos Torres"
];
$input = "gonza";
$needle = $input;
foreach(array_keys($equivalencias) as $letra){
  $needle = str_replace($letra, "\W?[".$equivalencias[$letra]."]\W?", $needle);
}
$needle = "/(.*$needle.*)/";                 // $needle == "/(.*\W?[gG]\W?onz\W?[aAáÁ]\W?.*)/"
$matches = [];
foreach($data as $nombre){
  preg_match($needle, $nombre, $match);
  if($match[1] != null){
    $matches[] = $match[1];
  }
}
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, aunque hace tiempo que descarté trabajar con arreglos para hacerlo directamente con base de datos. Voy a probar, seguramente me servirá para otros casos.

Comment: Yo usé archivos de texto en formato json como base de datos en una página porque era muy poca la información que se almacenaba y con muy poco tráfico, así que me quise ahorrar el tema de la configuración. Pero seguro que usar una base de datos es siempre la mejor opción por eficiencia, seguridad, escalabilidad, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Originalmente usaba una función para normalizar las cadenas, con dos arreglos para enviar como parámetros a `str_replace()`, algo como:

```
$buscar = ['á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú'];
$cambiar = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
```

Lógicamente, esto resultaba en dos arreglos muy extensos para tratar de considerar todas las opciones.

Después, intenté con `iconv()`, pero los resultados no son los esperados porque, dependiendo del idioma usado, los diacríticos son separados del caracter, por ejemplo:

```
$val = "á|â|à|å|ä ð|é|ê|è|ë í|î|ì|ï ó|ô|ò|ø|õ|ö ú|û|ù|ü æ ç ß abc ABC 123";
echo iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', $val);
// Resultado:
// 'a|^a|`a|a|"a d|'e|^e|`e|"e 'i|^i|`i|"i 'o|^o|`o|o|~o|"o 'u|^u|`u|"u ae c ss abc ABC 123
```

Al final, cree una función donde normalizo con `iconv()` y elimino los diacríticos, dejando solo letras, número y espacios con una expresión regular:

```
function normalize($string) {
    return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", '', iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string));
}
echo normalize($val);
// Resultado:
// a|a|a|a|a d|e|e|e|e i|i|i|i o|o|o|o|o|o u|u|u|u ae c ss abc ABC 123
```

Ahora funciona correctamente:

```
$users = [
    1 => ['login' => 'mpaz', 'name' => 'María de la Paz'],
    4 => ['login' => 'hglez', 'name' => 'Héctor González'],
    5 => ['login' => 'ctorres', 'name' => 'Carlos Torres'],
    7 => ['login' => 'mgomez', 'name' => 'Margarita Gómez'],
    9 => ['login' => 'cramirez', 'name' => 'Claudia Ramírez'],
    10 => ['login' => 'hectorm', 'name' => 'H. Miguel Ruiz'],
];
$buscar = 'arí';

function normalize($string) {
    return str_replace(['´','`','¨','^','~', "'", '"'], "", iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string));
}

function busca($valor, $users) {
    $valor = normalize($valor);
    foreach($users as $id => $v) {
        $login = normalize($v['login']);
        $name = normalize($v['name']);
        if(mb_stripos($login, $valor) !== false || mb_stripos($name, $valor) !== false) {
            echo '<p>' . $v['login'] . ' - ' . $v['name'] . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
busca($buscar, $users);

// Resultado:
// <p>mpaz - María de la Paz</p>
// <p>mgomez - Margarita Gómez</p>
```

**Nota:** Seguramente habrá ocasiones en que sea de utilidad (¿?), pero no puede considerarse como una buena opción frente a consultas a base de datos, porque consume más recursos (tiempo y memoria).

Comment: En realidad sería mejor normalizar la variable `$buscar` para convertirla en una expresión regular en vez de hacerlo con los datos dentro del ciclo. Publico un ejemplo en las respuestas.