# mostrar resultados de la busqueda de datos en un directorio local

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

solicito su ayuda para resolver un problema realmente de falta de conocimientos para realizar la tarea, mostraré que he hecho y que necesito hacer...

la tarea a realizar: "buscar desde un input tipo texto canciones dentro de una directorio local
Ej: c:\wamp\www\media\pop...

muestro que llevo hasta ahora

buscar.php // este es mi buscador con un input text simple. la busqueda comienza desde la primera letra que coloque...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
                            
    var consulta;
                                                                      
     //hacemos focus al campo de búsqueda
    $("#busqueda").focus();
                                                                                                
    //comprobamos si se pulsa una tecla
    $("#busqueda").keyup(function(e){
                                 
          //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo de búsqueda
          consulta = $("#busqueda").val();
                                                                       
          //hace la búsqueda
                                                                              
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "busqueda.php",
                data: "b="+consulta,
                dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: function(){
                      //imagen de carga
                      $("#resultado").html("");
                },
                error: function(){
                      alert("error petición ajax");
                },
                success: function(data){                                                    
                      $("#resultado").empty();
                      $("#resultado").append(data);
                                                         
                }
          });
                                                                              
                                                                       
    });
                                                               
 });

 </script>    
 </head>
 <body>

 <input type="text" id="busqueda" />
         
 <div id="resultado"></div>

 </body>
```

archivo busqueda.php donde recibo lo que viene del input text y lo proceso

```
<?php

$buscar = $_POST['b'];
   
if(!empty($buscar)) {
    buscar($buscar);
}
   
function buscar($b) {
    $dir = opendir('./media/merengue');
    $files = array();
   
        while ($current = readdir($dir)){
            if( $current != "." && $current != "..") {
                if(is_dir($dir.$current)) {
                    showFiles($dir.$current.'/');
                }
                else {
                    $files[] = $current;
                }
            }
        }

        var_dump($files);

        foreach($files as $key => $song) {
            //echo "$song <br>";
            $mp3 = explode('-', $song);
            $artista = $mp3[0];
            $titulo = $mp3[1];
            $tit = explode (".", $titulo); 
            $title = $tit[0];
            $musica = $artista. '-' .$titulo.'';
            //echo $files[0] ;
        }    
     }

 ?>
```

// En vardump($files); me muestra esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estuve haciendo pruebas con for, foreach, while, lo pasé tambien a Json pero no obtengo el resultado que necesito...

Necesito es que cuando escriba el nombre busque en $files el nombre de la canción y poder mostrar los resultados de la busqueda...

Lo que no se hacer es como paso los nombres de las canciones a un resultado de busqueda del input text...

De ante mano gracias por la ayuda.

editado:

usando este codigo con glob:

```
$track = glob('./media/merengue/*.{mp3}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($track as $file) {
    var_dump($file);
     }
 ?>
```

obtengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de alli no se como obtener las canciones ... alguien me podrá ayudar?

Comment: El problema es que lees todos los archivos sin verificar que coincidan con la cadena de búsqueda. Probablemente una "buena opción" sería filtrar con [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php). Por experiencia (y buenas recomendaciones de @A.Cedano), lo ideal sería que tengas la lista de canciones en base de datos para hacer más eficiente el proceso. Referencia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328565/c%c3%b3mo-encontrar-subcadena-insensible-a-tildes

Comment: Dado que es un ejercicio, ¿tienes que ser con las funciones que estás usando o se puede usar otras como [`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php)?

Comment: gracias por responder, me pueden proporcionar un ejemplo por favor. Triby, no lo coloco en base de datos porque si elimino o agrego mas canciones tendría que hacer el proceso también en la base de datos y es doble trabajo. una opción que estoy pensando es recorrer el directorio y crear un archivo con la lista y leerla desde allí, y cada vez que entre al subdirectorio independientemente que borre o cree nuevas canciones igual se recorre el directorio y se actualiza la lista... es una idea que también tengo en mente

Comment: @A.Cedano, puede ser con jquery, javascript, ajax, json, con lo que sea conta de que la busqueda arroje la canción que se escriba. (preferiblemente que no sea javascript), por mas que trato yo no entiendo las sentencias javascript, mis conocimentos no llegan todavia a entender la lógica de como trabaja...

Comment: Javascript trabaja del lado del cliente (navegador) y PHP trabaja del lado del servidor (base de datos, archivos en el entorno del servidor, etc). Son dos mundos diferentes pero complementarios casi siempre. En este mismo ejemplo, si tus archivos están en el servidor y quieres dar la posibilidad de buscar canciones a tus clientes (que pueden ser miles o millones en todo el mundo, a través de una web) entonces tendrás que usar ambos. El cliente escribiría lo que quiera en el input, tal y como lo tienes, y esos datos se enviarían al servidor vía Ajax para buscar lo que el cliente pidió ...

Comment: ... ahí entra en juego el servidor, buscando en su sistema de archivos, o en la base de datos, las canciones coincidentes y devolviéndolas al cliente. Así es como funciona la cosa más o menos, en casi todas las aplicaciones web.

Comment: Para buscar en el servidor, te recomendaría el uso de `glob()`, en el [Manual de PHP está explicado cómo funciona](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php#88250) Y en [este artículo](https://www.poftut.com/php-glob-function-to-match-path-directory-file-names-with-examples/) hay varios ejemplos de patrones de búsqueda. Por ejemplo, si quieres buscar sólo `.mp3` con el término  *bachata*  el patrón sería: `bachata?.mp3` y si quieres un archivo con cualquier extensión y el término *bachata* sería algo así: `bachata?.*`

Comment: tu comentario lo tengo claro, de hecho hice una prueba con glob, y obtengo la  matriz de las canciones, sé que php funciona del lado servidor y javascript, jquery, etc, trabajan del lado del cliente. Manejo un poco jquery, lo que siempre ha sido dificil es recorrer matrices y arrays para manipular los datos, uso codigos de ejemplos y los modifico y muchos funcionan. tengo la lista en una variable, solo que no se acceder a las canciones de la lista para poder hacer eso... alli está mi problema, desconozco totalmente como hacerlo... por eso vengo a pedir ayuda con un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es tan sencillo como remplazar las funciones actuales con `glob()`:

```
// Asegurar que tienes un valor correcto
$buscar = (isset($_POST['buscar'])) ? trim($_POST['buscar']) : '';

function buscar($b) {
    // Inicializar directorio
    $dir = './media/merengue';
    // Obtener archivos
    $files = glob("$dir/*$b*.mp3");
    foreach($files as $key => $song) {
        // Aquí realizas el proceso necesario
        // O puedes devolver la lista simple y procesar en javascript
    }
}
// Ejecutar
if($buscar != '') {
    buscar($buscar);
}
```

La función puede recibir comodines que operan igual que el comando `DIR` en MS-DOS o `LS` en Linux:

- `?`: Se interpreta como cualquier caracter (solo uno)

  - `a?.mp3`: Buscará archivos que inicien con a, seguido de cualquier otro caracter y la extensión .mp3
- `*`: Se interpreta como cualquier caracter (uno o más) y es el más adecuado para lograr lo que necesitas

  - `$b*.mp3`: Para buscar solo los archivos que comiencen con la cadena dada
  - `*$b.mp3`: Para buscar solo archivos que terminen con la cadena dada más la extensión
  - `*$b*.mp3`: Para buscar la cadena en cualquier posición

Comment: Guaoo triby, gracias por el codigo funcionó a la perfección... estoy analizando tu codigo, porque obvio quiero aprender. Me doy cuenta que en glob colocas la variable de lo que escribo en el input que por supuesto que el nombre que escriba el lo completará, buscará y mostrará, estoy es genial "jamás se me fuese pasado por la mente hacer eso"... de hecho hice un codigo muy parecido y que de tantas pruebas lo borré, no funcióno porque solo me faltaba poner la variable *$b*.mp3...  es esto lo que justamente no sabia armar... muchisimas gracias Triby... tu respuesta es la acertada....