# Sustituir vocales acentuadas y la ñ por no acentuadas y n en PHP y Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, string, yii2

Hola estoy trabajando con con Yii2 en el cuan tengo un formulario, uno de los campos (nombre etiqueta) pide el nombre de un campo que se agregara como una nueva columna a otra tabla con ese nombre ingresado, es por eso que quiero quitar los acentos y la letra ñ, tengo el siguiente código en el controlador:

omití un poco de código no relevante en el tema

```
$db = new yii\db\Connection(['dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2prueba2','username' => 'root','password' => '','charset' => 'utf8',]); //Conexion DB

$table = new Formularios;
$table->etiqueta = $model->etiqueta;
$table->longitud = 255;

$campo1 = str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($model->etiqueta)); //sustituyo espacios por '_'

// Aqui pretendo realizar las sustitucion
$campo2 = str_replace(
                    array("á","é","í","ó","ú","ñ"),
                    array("a","e","i","o","u","n"),
                    $campo1
                );

$table->nombreCampo = $campo2; // en este campo guardo el nombre de la columna que se creara ya sin acentos pero me marca error, aquí es curioso si lo dejo de la forma $table->nombreCampo = $model->etiqueta ósea con acentos no me marca error

$query = "ALTER TABLE vehiculos ADD ".$campo2." ".$tipoData."(".$table->longitud.");"; //La variable campo2 me marca error por que en la cadena me trae caracteres raros[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

if($table->insert()) 
{
    if($db->createCommand($queryDB)->execute() == 0) //Crea el campo en la otra tabla
    {
         //mas código
    }

}
```

En fin, no se que es lo que ocurre desde mi perspectiva tendría que funcionar pero no. Anexo imagen del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/376066/54039) hay una función para "normalizar" el texto, solo faltaría eliminar espacios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo solucione, el problema esta en que primero utilizaba el método strtolower el cual devuelve el resultado en codificación iso-8859-1 y al tratar de usar str_replace me devolvía caracteres raros, realmente no se en que consiste bien por que pasa eso, pero la solución fue primero utilizar el str_replace para reemplazar las letras y después usar strtolower

```
$campo1 = str_replace(
                array("á","é","í","ó","ú","ñ"),
                array("a","e","i","o","u","n"),
                $model->etiqueta
            );

$campo2 = str_replace(" ","_",strtolower(campo1));
```

Answer (score 5):

Yo uso esta función que [encontré aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59716139)

```
function replace_accents($str) {
   $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
   $str = preg_replace('/&([a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde|ring);/','$1',$str);
   return html_entity_decode($str);
}
```