# Normalizar una cadena de texto para Base de Datos - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una cadena de texto la cual quiero Capitalizar para que sea guardada en una base de datos.
El problema que ahora me he encontrado, es que la letra `Ñ` no la puedo capitalizar por métodos básicos.

```
$cadena = "Juan Carlos Muñoz España";
$new = strtoupper($cadena);
echo $new; //-> OUTPUT: "JUAN CARLOS MUñOZ ESPAñA"
```

Esto además, me llevó a descubrir que me ocurriría algo similar con los acentos

```
$cadena = "Juán Carlos Muñóz España";
$new = strtoupper($cadena);
echo $new; //-> OUTPUT: "JUáN CARLOS MUñóZ ESPAñA"
```

Y probablemente me suceda lo mismo si es que se presentan otros caracteres especiales.

¿Hay modo de evitar esto a través de métodos sencillos?
¿Hay forma de hacer el reemplazo con expresiones regulares?

Comment: Probablemente si usas [mb_strtoupper()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtoupper.php) funcione, porque la otra función no soporta caracteres multibyte y solo los ignora.

Comment: Con esa función la `ñ` pasa a ser `Ñ`, solo necesito encontrar la mejor manera de deshacerme de acentos y caracteres especiales.

Comment: Entonces revisa las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/328565/54039) seguramente te servirán.

Comment: Encontré algo más simple a mi parecer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

Comment: Un tanto similares, una con arreglos y otra con `iconv()`, ya nos contarás cuando hagas tus pruebas.

Comment: @Triby `iconv()` no es lo que quiero realmente, sino deshacerme de los carácteres especiales o acentuados.

Comment: Precisamente, eso era lo que buscaba en mi pregunta y, desde entonces, dejé de usar arreglos, porque podría colarse algún caracter no contemplado y, con `iconv()` tengo que hacerlo en dos pasos, uno para separar diacríticos y otro para eliminarlos. Pero eso ya es cuestión de preferencias, lo bueno es que pudiste solucionar de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Para el reemplazo de acentos y otros carácteres, he tomado la [siguiente respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373364/12429790):

`strtr` — Convierte caracteres o reemplaza substrings

```
$ignorar = array(
'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
$str = strtr($cadena, $ignorar);
```