# Buscar en una cadena de texto una palabra que se encuentra almacenada en una BD

Tags: php, mysql

Expongo mi duda, no se exactamente si el método `array_push` sea compatible con la búsqueda de string con `strrpos()` debido a que mi código no me arroja resultados al final del proceso o este realizando una mala practica.

Tengo el siguiente código, en el que realizo una llamada a la BD para realizar una consulta que me trae todos los productos fabricados y posteriormente los almaceno dentro de un array con el metodo `array_push`.

```
        <?php
session_start();
include('../conexion.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM prod_mst WHERE prod_tipo = 'FABRICADO';";
$result_prod = $conexion->query($sql);
$ar_prod = array();
while($prod = $result_prod->fetch_assoc()){// Recorro la consulta en captura de los resultados
    $prod_tipo = $prod['prod_descrip'];
    array_push($ar_prod, $prod_tipo);//Empujo los resultados a mi arreglo $ar_prod
};
```

**Información que me trae la consulta es:**

```
 1. Audi s6 2017
 2. Rueda de bici
 3. Bicicleta
 4. Caceta
 5. Sistema electrico
 6. Sistema de frenado
 7. Sistema de transmición
 8. Sistema de direccion
 9. Sistema de suspensión
 10. Motor
```

Mi siguiente paso es declarar mi cadena de texto en el que realizare la búsqueda y mediante un `foreach()` recorrer todo el array que genere con los datos de la consulta para así posteriormente comparar cada una de las palabras de mi array si hay alguna coincidencia con mi cadena de texto.

```
    $prod_padre = "B001 - Bicicleta";//cadena de texto en el que buscare
$i=0;
foreach($ar_prod as $val){//Recorro todo el contenido de mi arreglo
    $position = strrpos($prod_padre, $ar_prod[$i]);//Evaluó si hay alguna coincidencia con alguna de las palabras capturadas en el array con la cadena de texto 
    $ar_prod[$i];
    if ($position === false)
    {
        $meet = false;
    }
    else
    {// Si encuentro coincidencias, capturo la palabra y mi variable y cierro el bucle
        $palabra = $ar_prod[$i];
        $meet = true;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
};

if($meet==true)
{
    echo "La palabra buscada es: ".$palabra. " Posicion: ".$position;
}
else
{
    echo "No encontre nada";
}
?>
```

al final me arroja como resultado que no encuentra nada, no se que estoy haciendo mal en el proceso ya que hay coincidencia con la palabra Bicicleta de mi arreglo y la cadena de texto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio, si introduzco manualmente la información al array si me arroja las coincidencias.

```
$ar_prod = array("perro", "calle", "Bicicleta", "llanta");
$prod_padre = "B001 - Bicicleta";
$i=0;
foreach($ar_prod as $val){
    $position = strrpos($prod_padre, $ar_prod[$i]);
    $ar_prod[$i]."\n";
    if ($position === false)
    {
        $meet = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $palabra = $ar_prod[$i];
        $meet = true;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
};

if($meet===true)
{
    echo "La palabra buscada es: ".$palabra. " Posicion: ".$position;
}
else
{
    echo "No encontre nada";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es necesario armar primero el arreglo? ¿No sería mejor buscar directamente en la base de datos solo las coincidencias? Lectura recomendada: [MySQL LIKE](https://www.anerbarrena.com/mysql-like-5657/)

Comment: Es una opción, pero como cree un auto complit en el que te muestro en un string el ID del producto y su descripción, necesito comparar el resultado obtenido con los registros almacenados en BD

Comment: Precisamente, con base de datos es más rápida y precisa la comparación. Si lo haces con arreglos, tal vez luego te veas en los mismos problemas que yo tuve cuando hice [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/328565/54039).

Answer (score 0):

Necesito una captura de pantalla sobre que te devuelve la consulta exactamente, de esa forma podría saber si estás teniendo algún problema con las keys, lo cuál explicaría porque un array de strings simple te funciona y el resultado de la consulta no.

Con este approach te olvidas de las keys, así que te debería de funcionar:

```
<?php
$prod_padre = "B001 - Bicicleta";
foreach($ar_prod as $key=>$val) {
     $position = strrpos($prod_padre, $val);
     if ($position !== false)
     {
         echo "La palabra buscada es: ".$val. " Posicion: ".$position;
     }
};
?>
```

De esta forma te aseguras que siempre va a pintar por pantalla la palabra que ha coincidido con la búsqueda aunque haya coincidido en varias posiciones o varias palabras.

Comment: No exactamente, por que al momento de encontrar una coincidencia break me detendrá el bucle, capturándome la el valor en el que se detuvo, al final de la descripción del problema muestro otro ejemplo en donde el array lo rellene de forma manual y me arroja un resultado.

Comment: Cierto, ahora mismo lo edito la respuesta, puedes comprobar a ver si mi código te funciona? Lo he testeado y debería ir sin inconvenientes, por si el problema es algo que no se ve en la consulta. @CruzTrejoEdgar

Comment: Funciona, pero solo me arroja el primer registro que se encuentra en el array y no el que coincide, muchas gracias por tu apoyo!

Comment: Vaya, eso si que es raro... a mí con un array manual me saca el que toca independientemente de su posición, por mi parte no puedo aportar nada más sin ver exactamente que trae la consulta, espero que puedas resolverlo!

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución a mi problema, precisamente para que pueda funcionar correctamente se tiene que capturar cada dato obtenido por el array dentro de una variable, para que de esa forma pueda realizar comparación con la cadena de texto

```
$prod_padre = "B001 - Bicicleta";//cadena de texto en el que buscare
$i=0;

foreach($ar_prod as $val){//Recorro todo el contenido de mi arreglo
    $pro=$ar_prod[$i];//capturo el valor actual del array.
    $position = strrpos($prod_padre, $pro);//Evaluó si hay alguna coincidencia con alguna de las palabras capturadas en el array con la cadena de texto de forma correcta.
    if ($position === false)
    {
        $meet = false;
    }
    else
    {// Si encuentro coincidencias, capturo la palabra y mi variable y cierro el bucle
        $palabra = $ar_prod[$i];
        $meet = true;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
};
```