# ¿Cómo puedo validar los sufijos de palabras en php?

Tags: php

Buen día. Quisiera evitar que los usuarios ingresen palabras repetidas en una tabla de mi base de datos. Por ejemplo: perro = PERRO = Perro = perros = perrito. Y también si el usuario por error ingresa algo como "PRRO" o "PWRRO"

Estoy utilizando PHP, hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente, pero solo me valida los 3 primeros:

codigo.php

```
<?php

    $palabra_bd = 'perro';
    $palabra = 'perros';

    if (stristr($palabra_bd, $palabra) !== false){
        echo 'Encontrado';
    } elseif (stristr($palabra, $palabra_bd) !== false) {
        echo 'Encontrado';
    } else {
        echo 'No encontrado';
    }

?>
```

Espero que alguien darme una idea de qué hacer... Gracias

Comment: Lo primero lo puedes resolver a nivel de base de datos, declarando la columna con un collate case sensitive, el cual reconocerá como iguales  `perro, pérro, pérró, perró, PerRo, pErrO, pérrÓ` ... etc. como ves, es complicado, y te faltan muuuuchos casos, pues eso se resuelve simplemente declarando un collate case sensitive. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967) si trabajas con MySQL, si es otro SGBD la idea es la misma, sólo cambiará la forma en que declares la columna. Lo otro que dices, es una especie de corrector ortográfico, ese es otro tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haria algo así, a ver que te parece:

```
// dos tipos de sufijos, los que son agregados y los que restan caracteres al lexema
$sufijos = [
    '' => '0',  // coincidencia exacta
    'ito' => '-1',
    's' => '0',
];

// los pasamos todos a minúsculas, tanto el que viene de la BD como en que queremos comprobar
$palabra_bd = strtolower('perro');
$palabra = strtolower('perros');

// creamos un bucle para contemplar todos los casos
foreach ($sufijos as $sufijo => $desplazamiento) {
    $palabra_con_sufijo = substr($palabra_bd, 0, strlen($palabra_bd) + $desplazamiento).$sufijo;
    $expresion_a_buscar = '/^'.$palabra_con_sufijo.'$/';
    if (preg_match($expresion_a_buscar, $palabra, $coincidencias)) {
        echo "Encontrado: ".$palabra.' en '.$palabra_bd."\n";
    }
    $sim = similar_text($palabra, $palabra_con_sufijo, $perc);
    echo 'Cálculo similitud entre '.$palabra_con_sufijo.' y '.$palabra.': '.$sim . ' caracteres coincidentes. Un '.number_format($perc).'% de similitud'."\n";
}
```

**Explicación detallada:**

1. Al principio declaramos un array asociativo con los posibles casos y su **desplazamiento**. El *desplazamiento* es la cantidad de caracteres a extraer del lexema que viene de la base de datos. Un valor de -1 indica eliminar un caracter al lexema **antes** de aplicar el sufijo. Esto queda así con los sufijos que has aportado en tu pregunta, pero puedes incrementar los elementos para agregar más casos si conviene (que imaginó harás):

```php
$sufijos = [
    '' => '0',  // coincidencia exacta
    'ito' => '-1',
    's' => '0',
];
```

2. Luego pasamos a minúsculas las cadenas a buscar mediante la función [strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtolower.php), para facilitar las búsquedas despues:

```php
$palabra_bd = strtolower('perro');
$palabra = strtolower('perros');
```

3. Luego creamos un bucle para contemplar todos los casos de posibles sufijos recorriendo el array creado al principio, separando lo que es el sufijo en sí y su desplazamiento:

```php
foreach ($sufijos as $sufijo => $desplazamiento) {
```

4. Dentro del bucle creamos una nueva variable que contendrá el posible caso a encontrar ya con el sufijo incorporado. Para ello usamos las funciones [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) y [strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php) (**nota**: Podriamos usar [mb_strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strlen.php) en su lugar, pero no es una extensión por defecto en PHP y podria darnos un error):

```php
$palabra_con_sufijo = substr($palabra_bd, 0, strlen($palabra_bd) + $desplazamiento).$sufijo;
```

5. A continuación ponemos esa palabra a buscar dentro de una [expresión regular PCRE](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), buscando una coincidencia exacta de la misma que empiece (usando `^`) y termine (usando `$`) por ella, encerrada entre los delimitadores `/`:

```php
$expresion_a_buscar = '/^'.$palabra_con_sufijo.'$/';
```

6. Y ahora ya si realizamos la búsqueda mediante la función [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php):

```php
if (preg_match($expresion_a_buscar, $palabra, $coincidencias)) {
    echo "Encontrado: ".$palabra.' en '.$palabra_bd."\n";
}
```

Si se encuentra cualquier coincidencia aparecerá el mensaje del `echo`. En caso contrario nada. La variable $coincidencias es obligatoria ponerla en la función, pero no la vamos a usar para nada, pues tan solo queremos mostrar el `echo` en caso de que esta función no devuelva `false` en el condicional `if`.

7. Luego procedemos a calcular la similitud entre ambas cadenas, por si acaso, aun no siendo coincidentes, pudiera haber un alto porcentaje de similitud. Para ello usamos la funcion [similar_text()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.similar-text.php):

```php
$sim = similar_text($palabra, $palabra_con_sufijo, $perc);
```

Esta función nos devuelve la cantidad de caracteres coincidentes en la variable `$sim` y crea una variable float, en este caso la denominamos `$perc`, con el porcentaje de similitud que encuentra. Al ser de tipo float puede tener muchos decimales, los cuales suprimimos usando la función [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php).
8) Mostramos una línea en cada comparación para estudiar su porcentaje y ver como funciona esta función. A partir de aquí evaluaremos más adelante con que valores podemos considerar suficientes para determinar que es suficientemente coincidente para determinar que también es un posible caso a tener en cuenta para nuestro propósito final:

```php
echo 'Cálculo similitud entre '.$palabra_con_sufijo.' y '.$palabra.': '.$sim . ' caracteres coincidentes. Un '.number_format($perc).'% de similitud'."\n";
```

9. Y finalmente ya salimos del bucle con `}`.

Mientras he ido redactando esta respuesta se me ha ocurrido otra solución similar sin el uso de la función `preg_match()`, que sería esta:

```php
// dos tipos de sufijos, los que son agregados y los que restan caracteres al lexema
$sufijos = [
    '' => '0',  // coincidencia exacta
    'ito' => '-1',
    's' => '0',
];

// los pasamos todos a minúsculas, tanto el que viene de la BD como en que queremos comprobar
$palabra_bd = strtolower('perro');
$palabra = strtolower('perros');

// creamos un bucle para contemplar todos los casos
foreach ($sufijos as $sufijo => $desplazamiento) {
    $palabra_con_sufijo = substr($palabra_bd, 0, strlen($palabra_bd) + $desplazamiento).$sufijo;
    $sim = similar_text($palabra, $palabra_con_sufijo, $perc);
    if (number_format($perc) == '100') {
        echo "Encontrado: ".$palabra.' en '.$palabra_bd."\n";
    }
    echo 'Cálculo similitud entre '.$palabra_con_sufijo.' y '.$palabra.': '.$sim . ' caracteres coincidentes. Un '.number_format($perc).'% de similitud'."\n";
}
```

Como se aprecia en esta otra solución solo me baso en la función `similar_text()`. La explicación de la misma es de fácil deducción atendiendo a mis explicaciones previas.

La ejecución de ambas soluciones PHP debería mostrarte esto:

```php
Cálculo similitud entre perro y perros: 5 caracteres coincidentes. Un 91% de similitud
Cálculo similitud entre perrito y perros: 5 caracteres coincidentes. Un 77% de similitud
Encontrado: perros en perro
Cálculo similitud entre perros y perros: 6 caracteres coincidentes. Un 100% de similitud
```

**Nota final:** El comentario de la pregunta de @A.Cedano se deberia tener en cuenta también, pues a nivel del MySQL también se pueden realizar muchas cosas, y seria algo interesante a estudiar. Aún así, mi respuesta se basa en la petición inicial de hacerlo en PHP solamente.