# MSQL Select group by no diferencia entre n y ñ (MariaDB)

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, codificación

Tengo una consulta select de SQL:

```
SELECT PROVINCIA, POBLACION FROM zona GROUP BY PROVINCIA, POBLACION ORDER BY PROVINCIA, POBLACION
```

El problema, es que esta consulta no diferencia entre n y ñ, entonces tengo poblaciones como "Avellanosa de Muño" y "Avellanosa de Muno" (Escrito con N en vez de Ñ por un error humano) y la consulta me devuelve solo "Avellanosa de Muño" lo que ha escalado un error en todo el sistema.

Lo que debería de devolver la sentencia es tanto la "Avellanosa de Muño" como "Avellanosa de Muno" para evitar futuros errores, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que haga esto?

Motor: InnoDB

Muchas gracias

Comment: Esto es en qué motor de BD?

Comment: El motor es InnoDB

Comment: Muéstranos la estructura de tu tabla, la puedes obtener mediante `show create table zona;`. El problema que presentas tiene que ver con la *collation*, si vas a trabajar con caracteres en español lo más lógico es que apliques a la tabla o a la columna una collation que sepa diferenciar entre `n` y `ñ`. Lo puedes hacer desde la consulta también, pero no es lo ideal. Puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967) para más detalles.